# is it possible to call "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, fail);" only once

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-geocoding-api, google-geolocation

wants to call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, fail); only once i.e. at the time of initialization.
I wants to do:-

1. at the time of initialization Wants to set my Home Position(i.e. My current position).
2. When I start walking wants to update my current position only not my home position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register an event only once, you can use `addListenerOnce` and/or `addDomListenerOnce` depending on what event you want to listen to.

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

An example DOM event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(document, 'keyup', function (e) {

    // Listen ONCE for document keyup event
});
```

An example map event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function (e) {

    // Listen ONCE for map idle event
});
```

An example marker event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function (e) {

    // Listen ONCE for marker click event
});
```